# Synthetic event error when trying to type in textinput

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-state-management, react-state

I am building a login page in react-native. Whenever, I type something in the username field, I get a warning: **The synthetic event is reused for performance reasons** and the value of Text tag is not changed as desired. The code I have written is as below:

```
export default class LoginScreen extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            username: '',
            password: ''
        }
    }

    login = async () => {
        // const result = await appLogin(this.state.userName, this.state.password);
        console.log(`${this.state.username} ${this.state.password}`);
    };

    render() {
        return <View style={loginStyles.container}>
            <ImageBackground
                source={require('../../../assets/images/login.jpg')}
                style={loginStyles.backgroundImage}>
                <View style={loginStyles.titleContainer}>
                    <Text style={{fontSize: 40, color: 'grey', paddingVertical: 40}}>{this.state.username}</Text>
                </View>
                <View style={loginStyles.nestedContainer}>
                    <TextInput
                        placeholder={'username / email'}
                        style={[style.inputStyle, style.colorBlue]}
                        onChange={(username) => this.setState(username)}
                    />
                    <TextInput
                        placeholder={'password'}
                        textContentType="password"
                        secureTextEntry={true}
                        autoCapitalize="none"
                        autoCorrect={false}
                        style={[style.inputStyle, style.colorBlue]}
                        onChange={(password) => this.setState(password)}
                    />
                    <CustomRoundedButton
                        text={'Login'}
                        buttonStyle={[style.bgPrimary]}
                        onPress={this.login}
                        textStyle={[style.text20, {color: 'white'}]}
                    />
                </View>
            </ImageBackground>
        </View>
    }
};
```

Here is a screenshot to this warning.
[image]
Please help me find the solution to this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
 onChange={(username) => this.setState(username)}
```

with

```
onChangeText={(username) => this.setState({ username })}
```

and

```
onChange={(password) => this.setState(password)}
```

with

```
onChangeText={(password) => this.setState({ password })}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

TextInput's [`onChange`](https://reactnative.dev/docs/textinput#onchange) handler is passed a native event object, which you named `username` in the anonymous function. React state updates are asynchronous, so by the time react is updating state, the event is long gone (been placed back in the event pool).

Use [`onChangeText`](https://reactnative.dev/docs/textinput#onchangetext) instead, it receives the updated input text value.

```
onChangeText={(username) => this.setState(username)}
```

Update all your input change callbacks to use `onChangeText`.

Answer (score 0):

Your code:

```
onChange={(username) => this.setState(username)}
```

You should change for this:

```
onChangeText={(username) => this.setState({ username })}
```